# Recommended SQL Practice and Books

Tags: sql

Please recommend me some books and practices for me.
I am quite weak in SQL though not that bad in C# and VB.NET.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking something targeted to just ANSI Sql or something more specific like T-SQL/MSSQL, Oracle, MySql, Postgres?

Comment: Yes, I am looking something targeted to T-SQL/MSSQL.

Comment: I would suggest, unless you really have no choice, to also read a book that is not targeted to any specific RDBMS. Most times all your needs can be satisfied with standard SQL, and even if you deviate, it is good to know that you are doing it. Also, books that target particular engines tend to either assume that you understand relational database concepts (relational calculus, normalization, modeling) or they explain it only to a certain level, skipping a lot of important stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Itzik Ben-Gan has written three excellent books on SQL Server 2008 and T-SQL.  The best place to start is with 'SQL Server 2008:  T-SQL Fundamentals', and then from there to move onto 'Inside SQL Server 2008:  T-SQL Querying' and then finally 'Inside SQL Server 2008:  T-SQL Programming'.

If I could get all of the developers here to read these three books then I wouldn't need to spend half as much time as I do addressing quality concerns in our databases.

Answer (score 1):

Kalen Delaney's [SQL Server 2008 Internals](http://www.insidesqlserver.com/) will change the way you use SQL Server, by giving you such a thorough understanding of it all.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this book.It is great for the whole DBMS concepts including SQL

---

```
Database Management Systems: A Practical Approach to Design, Implementation, and
Management (Fourth Edition)
by Thomas Connolly and Carolyn Begg
Addison-Wesley, 2005
```

---

Answer (score 1):

[SQL: The Complete Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072118458) has been with me since day 1.  While the content in this book is excellent (easy-to-read, understand, great examples), I think its greatest strength is the strong appendix -- there isn't a language concept/keyword that isn't listed; its never let me down.

Oh, and its a few years old, so its dirt cheap now, too. :)